# Assign `@Environment` value to `Binding` parameter

Tags: swift

I'm creating a MacOS app and wanted to store the app state in memory and pass it around to a few components, but also update the state from those components.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@Observable
class Book {
  var title: String
  
  init(_ title: String) {
    self.title = title
  }
}

struct ParentView : View {
  @State private var myBook = Book("First title")
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Book title (Parent): \(myBook.title)")
      
      ChildView()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
        .background(.teal)
        .environment(myBook) // Add myBook to environment
    }
  }
}

struct ChildView : View {
  @Environment(Book.self) var myBook: Book
    
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Book title (Child): \(myBook.title)")
      
      TextField("Book title", text: myBook.title) // Error here!!!
    }
  }
}
```

This throws an error when I attempt to pass `myBook.title` as a `Binding` to the `TextField`.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
```

[image]

This makes sense but normally, but since the `Book` is an [`@Observable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/observation/observable()) class I can update the values and have the updates reflected across all usages.

What's the best way to assign an `@Observable` `@Environment` class property to a `Binding` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a `Binding`, you need to use `Bindable`:

```
struct ChildView : View {
  @Environment(Book.self) var myBook: Book
    
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Book title (Child): \(myBook.title)")
      
      @Bindable var myBook = myBook
      TextField("Book title", text: $myBook.title)
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation (which includes a similar example): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bindable